# How can i use MoveTowards method in Unity for more than one object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, position, instantiation, gameobject

I am planning to create `GameObjects` on random position and then slide to target position every frame.

I create one object `onstart()` manually and I used `MoveTowards` method in `update()` and it worked but i want to do same with many objects at the same time (about 10 objects): If i create more than one object it doesn't work.

This is what i have:

```
GameObject Go = Instantiate(M1, new Vector3(-5, 10, 0), Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 0)) as GameObject;
Go.transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(Go.transform.position, new Vector3(10, -20, 0), 0.05f);
```

Comment: get an average of whatever it is you are trying to head towards

Comment: Do you want to move many objects towards one object, or one object towards many objects?

Comment: As Ron has asked are you trying to swarm like a bunch of things to say your player or a single thing to a bunch of other things?  If its the first, then just have the same script on all, if its the latter, you need to average the group and head to the group

Comment: Actually i want that create object every second in update() and every object that i create slide to anathor positions (some random position). if the objects while go to its target position touch collider that i create i will destroy it.

Comment: Then use a list and iterate over it ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a new script, let's call it `Mover`. Give it `public Vector3 destination` and `public float rate` fields and an `Update` method that edits its position with `MoveTowards`:

```
public class Mover: MonoBehaviour
{
    public Vector3 destination;
    public Vector3 rate;

    void Update()
    {
        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, destination, rate * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

Attach a `Mover` to the `M1` prefab.

Then, when you instantiate each `M1`, set the `destination` and `rate` of its `Mover` component:

```
 GameObject Go = Instantiate(M1, new Vector3(-5, 10, 0), Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 0)) as GameObject;
 Mover goMover = Go.GetComponent<Mover>();
 goMover.destination = new Vector3(10, -20, 0); 
 goMover.rate = 3f;
```

Comment: thanx for answer but not exactly that i want.

Actually i want that create object every second in update() and every object that i create slide to anathor positions (some random position). if the objects while go to its target position touch collider that i create i will destroy it.   

ı cant Instantiate and movetowards every second in update()

Comment: To me that seems like exactly what I'm describing here. I'm sorry I don't seem to understand what your objective is.

Comment: @infiniteloop-0 Although, if you are using collision detection, you should probably rather use `Rigidbody` and setting their `velocity` rather than using `MoveTowards`. Your question doesn't mention them.

Comment: I told again but it was long so that i couldn't write here. Thanks for answer.

Comment: Hi again, @Ruzihm i tried again with little changing of your code. It worked very well. Thank you my friend.

Answer (score 0):

What you describe in the comments sounds like actually you have two tasks

- add a new object every second
- move all objects

Note: You can **not** use Collisions for detecting when an object reaches it's target! How do you know which collider belongs to which object? In other words: How would you make sure an object doesn't by accident collide with some other collider which was ment for another object? I'ld rather directly compare the positions instead.

```
public class ObjectController : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Here we will store all Transform references
    // linked to the according target position
    private Dictionary<Transform, Vector3> objects = new Dictionary<Transform, Vector3>();

    public GameObject prefab;

    // A simple timer for the spawning
    private float timer;

    // Here we will track objets that reached the Target and shall be destroyed
    List<GameObject> objectsToDestroy = new List<GameObject>();

    private void Update()
    {
        // Spawn a new object every second but only until maximum of 10 existing objects
        if(objects.Keys.Length < 10)
        {
            timer += Time.deltaTime;
            if(timer > 1f)
            {
                timer = 0;

                // However you generate your random start Position
                Vector3 startPos = GetRandomStartPosition();
                // However you generate your random target position
                Vector3 targetPos = GetRandomTargetPosition(startPos);
                var obj = Instantiate(prefab, startPos, Quaternion.Identity).transform;

                // Add this new transform and according target Position to the dictionary
                objects.Add(obj, targetPos);
            }
        }

        objectsToDestroy.Clear();
        // Now go through the items in objects and move them all
        foreach(var kvp in objects)
        {
            var obj = kvp.Key;
            var targetPos = KVP.Value;
            obj.MoveTowards(obj.position, targetPos, 0.05f * Time.deltaTime);

            // Do NOT use collisions for detecting if the object reaches but directly this
            if(obj.position == targetPos)
            // this uses a proximity of 0.00001f if you really need 0 instead use
            //if(Mathf.Approximately(Vector3.Distance(obj.position, targetPos), 0))
            {
                // mark this object for removal
                objectsToDestroy.Add(obj);
            }
        }

        // Finally remove all objects that reached from the dict and destroy them
        foreach(var obj in objectsToDestroy)
        {
            objects.Remove(obj);
            Destroy(obj);
        }
    }
}
```

Didn't know how you generate your random positions but you could e.g. have something like

```
private Vector3 GetRandomStartPosition ()
{
    return new Vector3(
        Random.Range(-10f, 10f),
        Random.Range(-10f, 10f),
        Random.Range(-10f, 10f)
        );
}

private Vector3 GetRandomTargetPosition(Vector3 startPos)
{
    return startPos + new Vector3(
            Random.Range(-1f, 1f),
            Random.Range(-1f, 1f),
            Random.Range(-1f, 1f)
        );
}
```

depending on your needs ofcourse.

Actually yes if you expect many objects (hundreds or thousands) to move parallel it is better to have only one component controlling them all in order to avoid overhead of `Update` calls. But for only 10 objects I would probably rather stick to [Ruzihm's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59536478/7111561) using one movement component for each object.

---

*Note: typed on smartphone but I hope the idea gets clear*

Comment: thanks for answer. Sorry i am new on unity. I couldn't run your code. it gave some bug

Comment: Would help to know what exactly is wrong ;) as said I'm typing only on my smartphone so it's possible that there is a typo .. also not sure from memory e.g. if it had to be `objects.Keys.Count` or `objects.Keys.Length` ;)